# Fetching data from an API in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm facing problem while fetching data from an API in ASP.NET Core MVC controller (imdb api).

The problem is I cannot deserialize the current JSON object into type
this is my code

```
List<Movie> movieList = new List<Movie>();

using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://imdb-api.com/en/API/Title/****/tt0110413"))
    {
        string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                
        var Movie = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(apiResponse);
        //movieList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Movie>>(apiResponse);
    }
}

return View();
```

My api data looks like this

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "tt0111161",
            "rank": "1",
        },...
    ]
}
```

I have an issue with deserialize - any help?

Comment: `i have an issue with deserilaze` what issue?  you can use https://jsonformatter.org/json-to-csharp to create C# classes for your JSON.

Comment: and how to use this exactly ?

Comment: Go to the website, paste you JSON, click on button. Copy the C# classes created there... use them in your code with whatever names you want. Try to deserialize the response to that class.

Comment: @yolo you have to post your json at least if you need some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure the structure of Movie is corresponding to your json data:

```
public class Movie {
        public List<Item> items { get; set; }
    }
    public class Item {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string rank { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use IMDbApiLib.

GitHub:
https://github.com/IMDb-API/IMDbApiLib

Nuget:
https://nuget.org/packages/IMDbApiLib

Movie's TitleData:
https://github.com/IMDb-API/IMDbApiLib/blob/master/IMDbApiLib/Models/TitleData.cs